# check box checked, download file, change text and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox '[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/992nypsn/3/)' When the user ticks on one of the checkboxes, it opens a new Window, which enables the user to view download a PDF once the checkbox button has been clicked. this then disables the download function so when the user ticks on the checkbox button again it activates the submit button.

The Trouble i am having is when the user clicks on the anything within the `terms-block`div is downloads the PDF. Initially how i want it when is the user clicks on the text 'terms and conditions' it opens the the PDF, once the PDF is open the text changes to 'i agree with the terms with a tick' that activates the submit button… can this be done

```
 <div class="terms-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="terms-agreed" class="form-terms" name="agreed" value="terms">
  <label class="terms-view" for="terms">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
 </div>
```

```
$(function() {
      var checkboxes = $("#terms-agreed"),
      submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
      enableSub(submitButt );
      checkboxes.on("click",function() {
        enableSub(submitButt );
        if (this.checked) window.open('{site_url}downloads/resellers/Standard_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf');
    });
});
```

Comment: couldnt you just set a link for Terms and Condition like  'I agree to the <a href="yourtermspath.pdf" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>'

Comment: nope that's not the task i have been given

Comment: sorry just saw the fiddle link right after i posted XD

Answer (score 2):

You should make something like this:

- Put a label with text "Terms and conditions" with some id
- In a div with some class with css set to display:none put the checkbox and the label with "I agree with terms and conditions".

  - Put a button with attribute disabled set to true, when user make a click in the "I agree (...)" text this button will change to enabled.

The code may look like this:

```js
 $(function() {
     $("#btnDownload").attr("disabled",true);
     $("#terms_and_conditions").on("click",function(){   /*window.open('{site_url}downloads/resellers/Standard_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf');*/
     $("#div_agree").show();
     });
     $("#terms-agreed").on("click",function(){
         if($(this).prop("checked"))
             $("#btnDownload").attr("disabled",false);
         else
             $("#btnDownload").attr("disabled",true);
     });
    });
```

```css
.terms_link{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#div_agree{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<div class="terms-block">
    <label id="terms_and_conditions" class="terms_link">Click to see terms and conditions</label><br/>
    <div id="div_agree">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="terms-agreed" class="form-terms" name="agreed" value="terms">
                                    <label class="terms-view" for="terms">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
                                </div>        
                                </div>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="btnDownload">Download</button>
```

Just adjust to your requeriments

I commented the window.open line.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Maybe you can hide the text "Click to see terms and conditions" once this has been clicked

Comment: how can do that ?? can you demonstrate in your answer please

Comment: can you demostrate how i can hide "Click to see terms and conditions" once this is clicked

Comment: Just add:
$("#terms_and_conditions").on("click",function(){   
$(this).hide();
/*window.open('{site_url}downloads/resellers/Standard_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf');*/
     $("#div_agree").show();
     });